# Filter array which satisfies condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have two array variables A and B.

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [1,3,4,5,7,8]
```

How do I use filter in array B which has same element in A like `B = [1,3,4]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array#filter` with `Array#includes`:

```js
const A = [1,2,3,4];
let B = [1,3,4,5,7,8];

B = B.filter(item => A.includes(item));
console.log(B);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get your required result using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

**DEMO**

```js
let A = [1,2,3,4],
      B = [1,3,4,5,7,8];

let result = B.filter(v => A.indexOf(v) >= 0);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.filter along with Array.prototype.indexOf

```
array1.filter(value => -1 !== array2.indexOf(value));
```